# Animejs: translateX 0 value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I need to animate some DOM element from a certain position to 0px but it doesn't work with animejs.

The css:

```
.animate {
  transform: translateX(50px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #12acec;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Here the JS:

```
anime({
  targets: '.animate',
  translateX: 0,
  duration: 300
})
```

If I inspect the element, I see that the element is set to translateX(0px) instantly ([fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/f5rh18L4/3/)).

But if I use value different from 0, it works ([fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/f5rh18L4/6/)).

Is it an animejs bug or I'm doing wrong?
If it's a bug, is there a way to handle 0 value on translateX with animejs?

**Update:**
My mine goal is to handle like succession animation ...

```
<div class="handwritting">
   <span>T</span>
   <span>e</span>
   <span>x</span>
   <span>t</span>
</div>
```

Js handwritting

```
anime({
  targets: '.handwritting span',
  opacity: 1,
  duration: 5000,
  delay: function (_, i) {
     return i * 100
  }
})
```

... but it doesn't work with translate but work with opacity. ([fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/f5rh18L4/20/))

Thank you

Comment: First things first.
`translateX(0) -> translateX(0)` implies there's no change. Hence no animation visible.
To fix this you need to provide some other value in CSS and then put translateX as 0 in anime object. Also remember to have transition-duration in your CSS so that animation is visible or it's simply snap to (0) without any visible effect

Comment: Into css I've put `transform: translateX(50px)`, so there is a change, 50px -> 0

Comment: Check the answer below, I've updated your fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to change translateX value and pass value as an array:

```
translateX: [50, 0] // [from, to]
```

Here the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f5rh18L4/25/)**.

Answer (score 0):

All the code in your first fiddle is correct except the missing part in css.

`transition-duration: 2s;` //2 seconds for change to happen. you can change it to required value

Check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5rh18L4/13/).

Comment: There isn't another way to do this? If I don't want to use the css property?
And how about handling timeline for example, do we need to to handle delay and duration into css? 

I made a little update to my answer! ;) Thank you for your response

Comment: You'd need to use delay as a calculated value instead of delay: function ... like `delay: 0` so that it can work. Check updated fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/f5rh18L4/23/`

Comment: But i need successive animation on span into .animate like the handwritting!
If it works, i will mark it as solved! :)